# webview font not getting applied

Tags: android

I have an android webview and the text in it has a font of sans-serif. I have the ttf file in assets/sans-serif.ttf
Here is the code

```
WebView webVw;
String webContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webVw=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webVw);
        webContent="%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22width%3A100%25%3Bheight%3A100%25%3Bposition%3Arelative%3Bleft%3A.1%25%3Btop%3A.1%25%22%3E%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22position%3Aabsolute%3Bwidth%3A31%25%3Bheight%3A42.22222222222222%25%3Bleft%3A36.375%25%3Btop%3A19.02313624678663%25%3Bcolor%3Argb(0%2C%200%2C%200)%3Bfont-size%3A50px%3Bfont-style%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3Asans-serif%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3A400%22%20%3EOverlay!%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22javascript%3A%20void(0)%22%20%20target%3D%22_blank%22%20%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsi0.twimg.com%2Fprofile_images%2F1490344068%2FLOGO_COGNIZANT_C_only_normal.jpg%22%20style%3D%22position%3Aabsolute%3Bwidth%3A4.875%25%3Bheight%3A10.444444444444445%25%3Bleft%3A0.625%25%3Btop%3A1.2853470437017995%25%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22position%3Aabsolute%3Bwidth%3A4%25%3Bheight%3A6.666666666666667%25%3Bleft%3A95%25%3Btop%3A1.5424164524421593%25%3Bbackground%3Argb(47%2C%206%2C%20246)%20none%22%20%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22cf-component%20buttonwrap%22%20style%3D%22position%3Aabsolute%3Bborder%3Dradius%3A5px%3Bwidth%3A4.25%25%3Bheight%3A4.222222222222222%25%3Bleft%3A6.125%25%3Btop%3A3.3419023136246784%25%3Bbackground%3Argb(6%2C%20115%2C%20233)%3Bfont-size%3A15px%3Bfont-style%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3Asans-serif%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3A400%22%20%3E%3Ca%20%20class%3D%22editableTxt%22%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cognizant.com%22%20target%3D%22_blank%22%3E%20Go!%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E";
        String head="<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'sans-serif';src: url('file:///assets/sans-serif.ttf');}body {font-family: 'sans-serif';}</style></head>";
      String HtmlString = "<html>"+head+"<body>"+webContent+"</body></html>";
    webVw.loadData(HtmlString, "text/html","charset=UTF-8");

    }
```

The webview displays the normal font but not sans-serif

Comment: I also faced the same problem with webview, webview is not taking custom font, but same font is applied to other controls. I dont know why webview is not applying the custom font, I am also loading html into webview

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

In your assets/fonts folder, place the desired OTF or TTF font (here MyFont.otf)
Create a HTML file that you'll use for the WebView's content, inside the assets folder (here inside assets/demo/my_page.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.otf")
}
body {
    font-family: MyFont;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: justify;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Your text can go here! Your text can go here! Your text can go here!
</body>
</html>
```

Load the HTML into the WebView from code:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo/my_page.html");
```

Take note that injecting the HTML through loadData() has not worked for me. I'd be curious to hear if anybody can get that working.

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead of it

```
webVw.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",HtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases if you tried many ways to solve this problem and you did not get your problem solved yet. you should try to check your font file correct name.open your font file and check font name, copy that and rename file to correct name.
In your html codes use correct name too.
I had this problem several times!